# php pass function and return back value to calling function

Tags: php

Here two arguments `img` and `dir` are passed to `img_upld` function. How to use `rslt['data']` in calling function `img_upld`. To be precise, first I upload image and if image is successfully uploaded then want to run insert query to avoid repetitive image upload code.

```
$this->img_upld($img, $dest);
```

I tried with

```
if($this->img_upld($img,$dest)){
    $data = $this->img_upld(); // obviously it says few arguments
    echo $data['status'];   
}



public function img_upld($img, $dir){
        $handle = new file_upld('data:'.$img);
        if($handle->uploaded){
            ...
            if($handle->processed){
                $rslt['status'] = 'success';
                $rslt['data'] = $handle->file_new_name_body;

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your question is totally unclear for me ..

Comment: you do not `return $rslt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $this->img_upld($img,$dest);
if($data){
    echo $data['status'];   
}



public function img_upld($img, $dir){
        $handle = new file_upld('data:'.$img);
        if($handle->uploaded){
            ...
            if($handle->processed){
                $rslt['status'] = 'success';
                $rslt['data'] = $handle->file_new_name_body;

            }
        }
        return $rslt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but probably you want to use `$data` after this if statement `if($this->img_upld($img,$dest)){` if it's true, you should return it from `img_upld()` function, like this:

```
 public function img_upld($img, $dir){
        $handle = new file_upld('data:'.$img);
        if($handle->uploaded){
            ...
            if($handle->processed){
                $rslt['status'] = 'success';
                $rslt['data'] = $handle->file_new_name_body;
                return $rslt; // new row
            }
        }
}
```

Also to avoid this problem `$data = $this->img_upld(); // obviously it says few arguments`

You should pass arguments like this:

```
if($this->img_upld($img,$dest)){
    $data = $this->img_upld($img, $dest); // changed row
    echo $data['status'];   
}
```

or you should set these params with default value, like this (it is best to do both):

```
public function img_upld($img = '', $dir = ''){
```

**Full code:**

```
$data = $this->img_upld($img, $dest); // changed row
if ($data) { // check if there is data
    echo $data['status'];
} else {
    echo 'There is no data';
}   


public function img_upld($img = '', $dir = ''){
        $handle = new file_upld('data:'.$img);
        if($handle->uploaded){
            ...
            if($handle->processed){
                $rslt['status'] = 'success';
                $rslt['data'] = $handle->file_new_name_body;
                return $rslt; // new row
            }
        }
        return false; // new row
}
```

Comment: Double execution of file uploading may cause the issues.

Comment: Just forgot to remove his if statement after added mine, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your function `img_upld(1,2)` has defined two input arguments. If you want to use it as `img_upld()` you need to change in on:

```
public function img_upld($img = '', $dir = ''){
```

`$img = ''` defines default value in case if it wasn't passed in it.

Also, if you wanna use `resultant array` you should return it from your method.

```
...
        if($handle->processed){
            $rslt['status'] = 'success';
            $rslt['data'] = $handle->file_new_name_body;

            return $rslt; 
        }
...
```

And here you can execute your function only once.

```
if($data = $this->img_upld($img,$dest)){ 
    echo $data['status'];   
}
```